# addFileAttachmentAsync error with files from azure blob storage

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, azure-blob-storage

I am developing an Outlook Add-in where I also want to attach some files to an Outlook Appointment.

I am able to upload files to the Azure blob/file storage successfully but if I want to attach these files via the `addFileAttachmentAsync` method I'll get a `Download failed` message in Outlook, the status of the result of the method is 'Succeeded' though.

The file is public available via the URL https://menatwork.blob.core.windows.net/outlookattachments/Icon80.png (tried both https and http)

If I use another URL (e.g. https://menatwork.azurewebsites.net/images/Icon80.png, or any other image you can find on the web) it works perfectly fine and the attachment is downloaded in Outlook.

The manifest file of the add-in contains the Azure domains but since it is working with other domains too (https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png), I guess the error has to do with the blob storage http response?

**Solution:**
Upgrade Outlook to the latest version (e.g. Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2110)) fixed the problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this as described because the first URL is returning a "The specified blob does not exist." error when viewed directly in a browser.

Comment: Sorry for that, blob is available again.

Comment: I tried the URL in both Outlook Desktop and OWA and it actually worked for me. Which Outlook client and version are you using? I used this command to test it: Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync("https://menatwork.blob.core.windows.net/outlookattachments/Icon80.png", "item.png", { asyncContext: null }, function (asyncResult) { console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult)) });

Comment: You are absolutly right, it really does work with the latest version

Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2110) 32-Bit