# addFileAttachmentAsync download failed for file hosted in azure blob storage

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, azure-blob-storage

I have created an Outlook web addin that attaches files to an email.

When using the "addFileAttachmentAsync" method of the Outlook JS API to attach a file that is hosted in Azure Blob Storage I get a "Download Failed" on the attachment. The response of the method is "Success" though.

Files hosted elsewhere attaches correctly.

This works perfectly in Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2259).
It breaks in Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.10827.20084).

I found a similar post on stack overflow which says it was fixed in Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2110). [Reference to the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149608/addfileattachmentasync-error-with-files-from-azure-blob-storage)

Could this functionality have been broken again?

Comment: Can you access the link in IE11 directly? Could you also share the link to the file so we can test it on our end?

Comment: Yes, the file opens in IE11 directly. You can test with the following link: https://qorussparkdfwedev.blob.core.windows.net/composecachedesktopv4rk3k8/test.docx

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress with the document link I've provided in the comment?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We have been able to repro the issue, and the bug has been put in the backlog, but is unknown when it will be fixed. Currently the problem repros even outside the addFileAttachmentAsync,  if you try to attach the file via URL from the UI, so the bug has been forwarded to the appropriate team. The workaround is currently to host the file elsewhere. Note that this workaround may be necessary going forward even after a fixed build comes out, as there will be older clients that still have this bug.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build 16.0.12625.10000 or later. Depending on the release channel you are on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.